ComPlus Applications no longer installing after upgrading from WiX v3 to v5
I have an installer that installs 13 ComPlus applications that works fine, and has worked for the last 8 or so years while on WiX v3.  After running the update process to WiX v5 using HeatWave and building the installer, after running it no longer installs the ComPlus applications.  An example of what most of the ComPlusApplication elements look like is below.
<Component Id="ExampleApplication" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" Guid="99C26517-64D1-4962-92BB-BE94F0A78B1F">
        <complus:ComPlusApplication Id="ExampleApplication" Name="ExampleApplication" Description="ExampleApplication" ApplicationAccessChecksEnabled="no" RunForever="yes" DumpOnFailfast="yes" MaxDumpCount="100" ThreeGigSupportEnabled="yes" Identity="[DOMAIN]\[USERNAME]" Password="[PASSWORD]"/>
</Component>

I'm not sure if I'm missing anything obvious, but the upgrade to v5 didn't modify the ComPlusApplication element at all, and I'm not sure if there is something new in the ComPlus extension that I haven't found.
Any idea or guidance is greatly appreciated!
I was looking through the verbose MSI Logs for a WiX v3 vs. WiX v5, and ComPlusInstallExecute runs in the v3 one, but doesn't run in WiX v5.  There is a hidden property in the logs for v5 like "Wix4ComPlusInstallExecute_X86", but no mention of a Custom Action of that name executing.
I tried adding that custom action manually to the InstallExecute sequence, but got the following error.
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="Wix4ComPlusInstallExecute_X86" After="Wix4ConfigureComPlusInstall_X86" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>

MSI (s) (D8:50) [14:31:01:224]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\WINDOWS\Installer\MSI35C2.tmp, Entrypoint: ComPlusInstallExecute
ComPlusInstallExecute:  Error 0x80070003: Failed to open rollback file, name:
CustomAction Wix4ComPlusInstallExecute_X86 returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
I tried a variety of things like adding child elements to the ComPlusApplication, adding  element to the component because that was a fix for something else in the past.
